# Java App to run a Kettle Job and receive the result

Tags: java, return-value, pentaho, kettle

It is possible to run a **Kettle Job/Transformation** from a **Java application**, and then get the result (a variable for example), in the same Java App?

Answer (score 2):

Although command line execution from Java likely isn't ideal, below would work. Just replace the cmd line with the appropriate paths and read in the output file of the job.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String cmd = "\"c:\\Program Files\\Pentaho\\pdi-ce-5.0.1.A-stable\\data-integration\\kitchen.bat\" -file=\"c:\\users\\exampleuser\\desktop\\examplejob.kjb\"";
        System.out.println(cmd);
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    /*READ OUTPUT FILE OF KJB IN TO OBTAIN VALUES*/


}
```

*http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?81151-Tutorial-Using-command-line-arguments-with-Kettle-and-scheduling
*http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html
*http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.01+Introduction+to+Spoon
*http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-execute-native-shell-commands.html
*http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Answer (score -2):

I'd try this to execute the transformation [this way](http://tejusparikh.com/2007/there-is-a-spoon-integrating-etl-into-yo.html). Kettle's Java API is quite readable.

The way described above does not cover retrieving the results. You'd need to add some custom logic to read the output data of the job. I'm not sure if there is a generic way to do that with ETL.

You can try grabbing the output into a HSQLDB or another in-memory DB, as described [here](http://devno.blogspot.com/2013/03/pentaho-kettle-etl-regression-with.html), and extract the output manually.

Comment: Please read [what makes a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) as if any of the links you provide isn't reachable, your answer becomes useless.